# Mathematics 101 using C

Tags: c, math

Can you help me with the code below? I am trying to make a program  where users need to choose the following options:
1 - Multiplication table
2- Test

When the user chooses either one and it's finished running, the program will prompt users to choose the following:
1 - Another multiplication table
2 - Another test
3 - Exit

Problem occurs when I choose the 2nd option. Whenever I try to exit (3rd option), it goes back to 1st option. Everything is normal when I choose the 1st option and then the 3rd option. How do I solve this?

Here's my code:

```
int c1;
int num;
int multi;
int num1, num2;
int answer;

printf("1 - Multiplication table\n");
printf("2 - Test\n");
printf("Choice: ");
scanf("%d", &c1);

while (c1 != 1 && c1 != 2)
{
    printf("\nInvalid selection. Please choose again.\n");
    printf("1 - Multiplication table\n");
    printf("2 - Test\n");
    printf("Choice: ");
    scanf("%d", &c1);
}

if (c1 == 1)
{
    do
    {
        printf("\nChoose a number ranging from 1 to 12.\n");
        printf("Choice: ");
        scanf("%d", &num);

        while (num > 12)
        {
            printf("\nInvalid selection. Please choose again.\n");
            printf("Choose a number ranging from 1 to 12.\n");
            printf("Choice: ");
            scanf("%d", &num);
        }

        printf("\nMultiply of %d\n", num);
        for (multi = 1; multi <= 12; multi++)
        {
            printf("%d x %d = %d\n", num, multi, num * multi);
        }

        printf("\nNext program?\n");
        printf("1 - Another multiplication table\n");
        printf("2 - Test\n");
        printf("3 - Exit\n");
        printf("Choice: ");
        scanf("%d", &c1);

        while (c1 != 1 && c1 != 2 && c1 != 3)
        {
            printf("\nInvalid selection. Please choose again.\n");
            printf("1 - Another multiplication table\n");
            printf("2 - Test\n");
            printf("3 - Exit\n");
            printf("Choice: ");
            scanf("%d", &c1);
        }

    } while (c1 == 1);
}

if (c1 == 2)
{
    do
    {
        printf("\nEnter 1st number: ");
        scanf("%d", &num1);
        printf("Enter 2nd number: ");
        scanf("%d", &num2);
        printf("Your answer is: ");
        scanf("%d", &answer);

        if (answer == num1 * num2)
        {
            printf("\nYou are correct. The answer for %d times %d is %d.", num1, num2, num1 * num2);
        }
        else if (answer != num1 * num2)
        {
            printf("\nYou are incorrect. The answer for %d times %d is %d, not %d.", num1, num2,
                num1 * num2, answer);
        }

        printf("\nNext program?\n");
        printf("1 - Multiplication table\n");
        printf("2 - Test\n");
        printf("3 - Exit\n");
        printf("Choice: ");
        scanf("%d", &c1);

        while (c1 != 1 && c1 != 2 && c1 != 3)
        {
            printf("\nInvalid selection. Please choose again.\n");
            printf("1 - Multiplication table\n");
            printf("2 - Test\n");
            printf("3 - Exit\n");
            printf("Choice: ");
            scanf("%d", &c1);
        }

        do
        {
            printf("\nChoose a number ranging from 1 to 12.\n");
            printf("Choice: ");
            scanf("%d", &num);

            while (num > 12)
            {
                printf("\nInvalid selection. Please choose again.\n");
                printf("Choose a number ranging from 1 to 12.\n");
                printf("Choice: ");
                scanf("%d", &num);
            }

            printf("\nMultiply of %d\n", num);
            for (multi = 1; multi <= 12; multi++)
            {
                printf("%d x %d = %d\n", num, multi, num * multi);
            }

            printf("\nNext program?\n");
            printf("1 - Another multiplication table\n");
            printf("2 - Test\n");
            printf("3 - Exit\n");
            printf("Choice: ");
            scanf("%d", &c1);

            while (c1 != 1 && c1 != 2 && c1 != 3)
            {
                printf("\nInvalid selection. Please choose again.\n");
                printf("1 - Another multiplication table\n");
                printf("2 - Test\n");
                printf("3 - Exit\n");
                printf("Choice: ");
                scanf("%d", &c1);
            }

        } while (c1 == 1);
    } while (c1 == 2);
}
```

Comment: Your code indentation is inconsistent. Please [edit] and fix it.

Comment: Try using a debugger or keep printing values every step of the way.

Comment: Your problem is probably that there are some unexpected or unhandled characters sitting on the input stream.  This is a common problem with programs that use `scanf` for input.  You need to check `scanf`'s return value -- especially the `scanf("%d", &c1)` call -- to make sure each call read as many values as you expect.  And if it didn't, you must find some way to discard the unexpected or unhandled input.  (This can be frustrating and difficult.  It's why I don't recommend using `scanf` at all.)

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] with emphasis on minimal

Comment: Please [edit] your code to reduce it to a [mcve] of your problem.  Your current code includes much that is peripheral to your problem - a minimal sample normally looks similar to a good unit test: only performing one task, with input values specified for reproducibility.

Answer (score 1):

The **do..while** loop in C executes one time before checking. In the second **if**: "if (c1 == 2)" your code first performs the test then it asks again to choose. Even if your answer is "3" it executes one time the code in the following **do..while** section which is actually the code for the "multiplication table".

You can use the **while** loop instead of the **do..while**. However the code seems overcomplicated and some sections are repeated I'll suggest you to review the logic (also consider to use the **switch** statement).

Comment: Specifically, one way to refactor the logic would be to write the program as a finite state machine, with a single block of menu code, and data about which options to display and which state each one leads to.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. Apparently, do while loop does not work well. Had to change to while loop. Here's the code:

```
int c1;
int num;
int multi;
int num1,num2;
int answer;

printf("1 - Multiplication table\n");
printf("2 - Test\n");
printf("Choice: ");
scanf("%d",&c1);

while(c1!=1 && c1!=2){
    printf("\nInvalid selection. Please choose again.\n");
    printf("1 - Multiplication table\n");
    printf("2 - Test\n");
    printf("Choice: ");
    scanf("%d",&c1);
}

while(c1==1 || c1==2){
if(c1==1){
printf("\nChoose a number ranging from 1 to 12.\n");
printf("Choice: ");
scanf("%d",&num);

while(num>12){
printf("\nInvalid selection. Please choose again.\n");
printf("Choose a number ranging from 1 to 12.\n");
printf("Choice: ");
scanf("%d",&num);
}

printf("\nMultiply of %d\n",num);
for(multi=1;multi<=12;multi++){
printf("%d x %d = %d\n",num,multi,num*multi);
}

}else if(c1==2){
    printf("\nEnter 1st number: ");
    scanf("%d",&num1);
    printf("Enter 2nd number: ");
    scanf("%d",&num2);
    printf("%d times %d equals to: ",num1,num2);
    scanf("%d",&answer);

    if(answer==num1*num2){
        printf("Your answer is correct! %d times %d equals to %d.",num1,num2,num1*num2);
    }else if(answer!=num1*num2){
        printf("Your answer is incorrect! %d times %d equals to %d, not %d.",num1,num2,num1*num2,answer);
    }
}

printf("\n\nNext program?\n");
printf("1 - Another multiplication table\n");
printf("2 - Test\n");
printf("3 - Exit\n");
printf("Choice: ");
scanf("%d",&c1);

while(c1!=1 && c1!=2 && c1!=3){
printf("\nInvalid selection. Please choose again.\n");
printf("1 - Another multiplication table\n");
printf("2 - Test\n");
printf("3 - Exit\n");
printf("Choice: ");
scanf("%d",&c1);
}
}
```

Comment: The do..while works as expected. It executes one time before checking.

Comment: You have not taken on board the advice from @SteveSummit. If you want robust code it is *essential* to check that user or file input happens the way you expect it to.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't rely on getting the correct input from `scanf()`, the safer option is to read the input using `fgets()` and convert the value to an int using `atoi()`.

```
int getValidNumberInput(void)
{
    char buf[BUFSIZ];
    int value = 0;

    if (fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), stdin) != NULL)
        value = atoi(buf);

    return value;
}
```

The `atoi()` function returns 0 for a non numeric value so it's perfectly suitable for you needs.

As mentioned in the comments, the logic of the program is easily simplified by using a `while()` loop and a `switch()` statement.

```
int main(void)
{
    bool hasLooped = false;
    bool invalidChoice = false;
    int choice;

    while (1)
    {
        /* Display the relevant menu */
        displayProgramMenu(hasLooped, invalidChoice);

        /* Get the selected menu choice */
        choice = getValidNumberInput();

        if (choice < 1 || choice > 3)
            invalidChoice = true;
        else
            invalidChoice = false;

        /* Perform the chosen action */
        switch (choice)
        {
        case 1:
            doFirstOption();
            hasLooped = true;
            break;
        case 2:
            doSecondOption();
            hasLooped = true;
            break;
        case 3:
            exit(0);
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

The use of the boolean variables allows the complexity to be moved into functions where it is easy to reason about.

```
void displayMenu(bool hasLooped, bool showInvalidMsg)
{
    if (showInvalidMsg)
        printf("\nInvalid selection. Please choose again.\n");
    else if (hasLooped)
        printf("\nNext program?\n");

    if (hasLooped)
        printf("1 - Another multiplication table\n");
    else
        printf("1 - Multiplication table\n");

    printf("2 - Test\n");
    printf("3 - Exit\n");
    printf("Choice: ");
}
```